# How can i set focus to specific index of the text in a text box?

Tags: vb.net

When i call TextBoxNameHere.Focus() it sets focus BUT it highlights the contents of the text box

I need it to set the cursor to be at the last character so if someone presses a key after that it doesn't erase the content, I have searched through a great deal of questions, but most of them are just asking how to set focus which i already know =|

Comment: Winforms? Wpf? Windows Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually do something like:

```
txtbox.Select(txtbox.Text.Length, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var value = TextBoxNameHere.val();
TextBoxNameHere.Focus();
TextBoxNameHere.val(value);
```

As in, reset the value after giving focus